# Question about Wanda's actions in the Doctor Strange 2 finale

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

Please note - this question contains spoilers regarding the ending of  "Doctor Strange and the Multiverse of Madness".

> When Wanda destroyed the Darkhold and every other one in the universe did she also destroy the castles since that’s where they were originally transcribed?

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi SE! This question will likely garner a few downvotes because it's largely a spoiler for a movie that just came out this weekend. I edited it so that there's more to the question than just a big spoiler block, but please don't let any downvoting discourage you from the site or future questions/answers. I haven't seen the film yet myself, but perhaps someone who has will post the answer for you.

Answer (score 11):

**Warning: heavy spoilers for the film below.**

Near the end of the film, Wanda states the following:

> WANDA: I opened the Darkhold. I have to close it. No one will ever be tempted by the Darkhold again.

She then destroys the [Darkhold Castle](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Darkhold_Castle) in her own reality, and shortly after that, in a different reality, we see that reality's copy of the Darkhold book spontaneously combust, with Strange taking that to mean that she must've destroyed the Darkhold in every universe.

> DR: STRANGE: So she destroyed the Darkhold in every universe.

The film just came out, so that's literally all we have to go on. Before I go any further, let me get a couple of provisos out of the way:

- Firstly, we don't strictly know that there's actually a Darkhold Castle in every reality, or even multiple realities. I tend to think it likely does (or did) exist in multiple realities, based on how timeline branching has been shown to work in *Loki* and *What If...?*. But for all we know, the Darkhold Castle we saw destroyed by Wanda could've been the only one in the entire multiverse.
- Secondly, we don't strictly know that Strange was right to conclude that the Darkhold had been destroyed in every reality, be it just the books, or the books and the castles (if there were multiple castles).

With that being said, from a purely logical standpoint, it stands to reason that Wanda would've wanted both the books and the castles destroyed in every reality they existed in. She clearly recognised the danger of leaving the castles intact -- as evidenced by the fact that she destroyed the one in her reality -- so leaving Darkhold Castles intact in any other realities would've foiled her stated objective of ensuring that no one would ever be tempted by the Darkhold again.

Admittedly, the evidence currently available to us is implicit rather than explicit on this point. So until or unless clearer evidence comes along, each individual viewer is left to draw their own conclusions.

Comment: I'm not convinced there are castles in every reality though that's just an opinion.  It seems to me if only one universe has a full blown scarlet witch (again IF) and there's only one book of Ashanti in the entire multiverse that there is some symmetry to having only one original darkhold castle.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - My answer isn't intended to assert that there's necessarily a Darkhold Castle in every reality. Merely that, however many there were, it's logical to think that Wanda would've wanted all of them destroyed.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - That said, since we were told that the spells in the Darkhold book in Wanda's reality were transcribed from the castle in her reality, the question is begged: if there was only one Darkhold Castle in the multiverse, then where were the spells in all the other Darkhold books transcribed from? Or are you positing that the books were the original source in every other reality?

Comment: I'm not asserting much either.  But I could posit the various realities are leftovers from the last mutliverse war and the current branching from the Loki series. So personally I'm taking it literally that the multiverse's one scarlet witch destroyed one castle that was apparently entangled with every paper copy in the multiverse. I personally think the MCU castle is the source for all copies and suspect that there is not other castles.  Merely my preference for 1 to 1 symmetry with 1 book of Ashanti.  (Which the multiverse seems to be aware of despite only 1 copy existing).

Comment: Just because Strange says it, doesn't mean it's actually true either. Sometimes they're stating what they think, not what they know, and even what they know could be technically wrong in that universe. Hard to know if it's a narrative truth or not.

Comment: @Derek Agreed. Characters can be unreliable.  Also I suppose for LogicDictates I suppose magic castles can be entangled across the multiverse too - but that seems like an Achilles heel design flaw.  And I don't think Wanda is that powerful to wreck multiple castles independently - but my opinions don't mean anything.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - If you go by the rules stated/implied by _Loki_ and _What If...?_, it follows that every time a new timeline branches out from a previous one, everyone and everything that existed in the previous reality would be 'cloned' as part of the formation of the new one. There should therefore be many Darkhold Castles sitting atop many Wundagore Mountains.

Comment: @LogicDictates Perhaps that means that the Darkhold is so old that it existed before any branches were created?

Comment: @Turbo - From what we've seen in _Loki_ and _What If...?_, branches can occur at various points in the past, the present, and presumably the future as well, since the past, present and future all exist simultaneously from the POV of anyone looking at the Sacred Timeline from the outside. Therefore, since it's clearly established that the Darkhold Castle exists in the present day, we know that it's existed in time periods where branches can occur. If it's been around for a very long time, that just means there are _more_ points along the Sacred Timeline where it could be duplicated.

Comment: @LogicDictates:   You so easily could have said *Logic dictates* instead of *Logically speaking*...

Comment: Apparently we're supposed to know what the Darkhold is because we've watched the finale of Wandavision (and all of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* and *Runaways*)? Or maybe I feel asleep....

Comment: @Mazura yes, or Agent Carter season 2, although the Marvel Studios prop is a completely different book to the Marvel Television prop.